# How to make specific fields read only when "Edit Read Only Fields" Administrative Permission is true

Tags: permissions, profile

Is there a way to make a specific field read only for a specific profile, but allow that profile to have 'Edit Read Only Fields' Administrative Permission set to true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Edit Read Only Fields is the override for both configurable Read-Only flags, namely Field Level Security and Page Layout configuration. Your choices are either a validation rule or some logic (Before Save Flow, Trigger, Workflow Field Update, Processes) to revert the value during/after saving.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help and for giving me possible options to consider! :)